# How can I access a button name if it was created in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, button

I'm currently trying to create a GUI for interacting with lines in a .txt file in order to sort the content of some freezer boxes. However it's difficult for me to interact with a specific line when i create a lot of buttons with a  for-loop such as this:

```
def create_boxes(self):
    for r in range(0,10):
        for c in range(0,10):
            self.button = Button(root, text='%s.%s'%(r,c),borderwidth=1 ,command= lambda: self.replace_line("Freezercontent.txt", r*10+c , input("What would you like in this slot"))).grid(row=r,column=c+5)
```

In the replace line function the second parameter is the linenumber the specific button needs to change. The solution i have does not work because when the lambda function is called upon with command the for-loop has finished. Meaning every button i click only changes the last line...

How can i access the buttons name given with the  `text="somename"` argument? Or is there an even smarter way of doing it?

Thanks and kind regards Emil H.

Comment: You probably need to keep a reference to it, outside of the loop

Comment: Why do you need to access the individual buttons?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, Ben and Peter Wood, keeping track of the buttons seems to only provide part of the solution as it is still only the command function of the last button i invoke when clicking it... seems to be related to my (most likely erroneous) use of the lambda function since flipvargas class definition has solved the last part of my problem. But thank you all! I'm new here but so far it truly seems like a great forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies elsewhere.

I suggest not using lambda but instead creating a class which can be initialized during call to button with those coords of buttons.

The inner working would be in the class itself and it would know of its coords.  You should create arrays of buttons also as suggested before me.

```
class Some:
    def __init__(self, r, c):
       self.r = r
       self.c = c
    def __call__(self):
       # do what you need and access coords as self.c and self.r

 Button(root, text='%s.%s' % (r,c), borderwidth=1, command=Some(r, c) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've currently coded it, it will let you access the last button created with `self.button`. You could change this into a dictionary, and store them all there:

```
def create_boxes(self):
    self.buttons = {}
    for r in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            text = '%s.%s' % (r, c)
            self.buttons[text] = Button(root, text=text, borderwidth=1, command=...)
```

Then you can use `self.buttons['1.1']` to get the button you need, etc.

Comment: or append all buttons in to a list and check `contained text`.  But dict better than list methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to store all the buttons:

```
def create_boxes(self):
    def make_replacer(r, c):
        def replacer():
            prompt = "What would you like in this slot"
            self.replace_line("Freezercontent.txt",
                              r * 10 + c,
                              input(prompt))).grid(row=r,column=c+5)
        return replacer

    self.buttons = [Button(root,
                           text='%s.%s' % (r,c),
                           borderwidth=1,
                           command=make_replacer(r, c))
                    for r in range(0,10)
                    for c in range(0,10)]
```